# how to update a cart with product details selected thourgh selects or radio's

Tags: php, jquery

here is an example:

http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MC375LL/A?mco=MTc0Njg1NzE

each radio button looks something like this:

```
<input type="radio" value="065-0338" name="option.aperture" id="coherent_id_53">
```

when one of them is selected the price on the right changes.

i don't understand where the value is stored that relates to this radio option. i have viewed the source but cant make it out. How can i do something like this? i tried looking online but i cannot find anything. do you know of a source that i can read or maybe if you can write a quick explanation and i can piece it together? thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is JavaScript at the end of the source code:

```
<script> 
// <![CDATA[
                    Event.onLoad(function onLoad() {
                        var configData = {"content":{"summary":{"overnightShipping":"Next business day delivery available","freeShipping":"Free Shipping","prices":{"total":"$1,499.00"},"part":"MC375LL/A","options":[{"isNone":false,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-9182","label":"2.66GHz Intel Core 2 Duo","metricsLabel":"2.66GHz Intel Core 2 Duo","option":"option.macbook_processor"},{"isNone":false,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-9184","label":"4GB 1066MHz DDR3 SDRAM - 2x2GB","metricsLabel":"4GB 1066MHz DDR3 SDRAM - 2x2GB","option":"option.macbookpro_memory"},{"isNone":false,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-9188","label":"320GB Serial ATA Drive @ 5400 rpm","metricsLabel":"320GB Serial ATA Drive @ 5400 rpm","option":"option.macbook_hard_drive_al"},{"isNone":false,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-9194","label":"SuperDrive 8x (DVD±R DL/DVD±RW/CD-RW)","metricsLabel":"SuperDrive 8x (DVD±R DL/DVD±RW/CD-RW)","option":"option.macbookpro_optical_drive"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"none","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.apple_led_displays"},{"isNone":false,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-9208","label":"Backlit Keyboard (English) / User's Guide","metricsLabel":"Keyboard (Local) & User's Guide (Local)","option":"option.macbook_keyboard_al_and_os"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-7672","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.iwork"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-7673","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.aperture"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-7674","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.final_cut_express"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-7675","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.logic_express"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-8307","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.filemaker"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-8198","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.microsoft_office_consumer"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-9198","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.dvi_adapter"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"none","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.dual_link_dvi_adapter"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"065-9200","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.vga_adapter"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"none","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.magsafe_airline_adapter"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"none","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.apple_remote"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"none","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.macbook_applecare"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"none","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.mobileme"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"none","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.one_to_one"},{"isNone":true,"isUpgrade":false,"value":"none","label":"None","metricsLabel":"None","option":"option.printer_offers"}]},"priceDeltas":{"magsafe_airline_adapter":{"none":"","MB441Z/A":"[Add $49.00]"},"macbook_keyboard_al_and_os":{"FZ065-9208":"","E065-9208":"","065-9208":"","JZ065-9208":""},"apple_led_displays":{"MC007LL/A":"[Add $999.00]","none":""},"macbookpro_memory":{"065-9184":"","065-9185":"[Add $400.00]"},"final_cut_express":{"065-7674":"","065-7682":"[Add $199.00]"},"printer_offers":{"H2618LL/A":"[Add $199.95]","H2400LL/A":"[Add $299.95]","none":"","H1355LL/B":"[Add $99.95]"},"apple_remote":{"MC377LL/A":"[Add $19.00]","none":""},"iwork":{"065-9263":"[Add $69.00]","065-7672":"","065-9172":"[Add $49.00]"},"logic_express":{"065-7675":"","065-9171":"[Add $199.00]"},"aperture":{"065-0338":"[Add $199.00]","065-7673":""},"microsoft_office_consumer":{"065-0276":"[Add $119.95]","065-0278":"[Add $199.95]","065-8198":""},"dual_link_dvi_adapter":{"MB571Z/A":"[Add $99.00]","none":""},"dvi_adapter":{"065-9199":"[Add $29.00]","065-9198":""},"mobileme":{"BG140LL/A":"[Add $119.00]","none":"","BG139LL/A":"[Add $69.00]"},"vga_adapter":{"065-9200":"","065-9201":"[Add $29.00]"},"macbook_hard_drive_al":{"065-9192":"[Add $750.00]","065-9191":"[Add $300.00]","065-9188":"","065-9193":"[Add $1,400.00]","065-9189":"[Add $100.00]"},"one_to_one":{"D4213Z/A":"[Add $99.00]","none":""},"macbook_applecare":{"S3136LL/A":"[Add $249.00]","none":""},"filemaker":{"065-8307":"","065-9806":"[Add $299.95]","065-9373":"[Add $49.95]"}},"learnMoreUrl":"/us/configureLearnMore","creditMessage":"<a href=\"http://store.apple.com/us/instant_credit\">6 or 12 month special financing options<\/a>","nonCollapsibleCategories":["promotions"],"collapsibleCategories":["hardware","presoftware","service_and_support","accessories"]},"url":"/us/configUpdate"}
,
                            configController = new apple.cto.ConfigurationsViewController($('page'), {});
                            configController.configData.set(configData);
                    });


                    // new apple.widget.SlidingTrackView($('slider-track'), {cleanup: false});
                // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: thanks but is there something a little bit more simpler to understand?

Comment: Actually that's all you need to know. When a checkbox is clicked, the script fetches the data from `configData` and updates the price.